# How to pass data frames between tasks in Airflow

Tags: airflow

I need to pass a data frame to ssh operator and store the data frame as a file on the server, initially, I thought xcom is an appropriate option to pass data between tasks, but it seems the is a size limit of using xcom as its content is being saved in the metadata of Airflow and xcom is useful when size of the data is small, what other options are available to pass large dataframe between tasks?

Comment: You can set custom xcom backend on S3/GCS and avoid the size limit however I still would not recommend using XCOM to pass data like that. Just don't end a task with data frame. write it to some shared storage and then the next task (SSHOperator) can read it.

Comment: @elad is right, you can use custom xcom backend. Here's article with [example than handles pandas DataFrames](https://medium.com/apache-airflow/airflow-2-0-dag-authoring-redesigned-651edc397178#custom-xcom-backend). The idea of such backend is to use shared storage (GCS, S3 etc) and remove boilerplate code for downloading and uploading the data.

Comment: xCom is not meant for massive data exchange. A better way would be to store the data and pass the location between the tasks.

Answer (score -1):

Custom XCom backend is the solution to exchange large volume of data between tasks in a Airflow DAG. We have implemented a vineyard XCom backend as a airflow provider that supports your case well (https://v6d.io/notes/airflow.html), with the vineyard XCom backend, you could have tasks like

```py
    @task()
    def extract():
        order_data_dict = pd.DataFrame({
            'a': np.random.rand(100000),
            'b': np.random.rand(100000),
        })
        return order_data_dict
```

It doesn't require any modification or user's existing code, and compared with the S3Backend of GCS backend, vineyard can share large volume of data without extra copy and serialization/deserailization.

Comment: downvoting because this (1) is promoting a company ("vineyard can share large volume of data..."), (2) does not have an explicit disclaimer and (3) does not offer an implementation in the answer or even a sketch of what a XCom backend could look like.

Comment: Hi @william_grisaitis we do have the implementation for the backend: https://github.com/v6d-io/v6d/blob/main/python/vineyard/contrib/airflow/README.md. Free to reach out if you meet any problem during this process.